# Laravel login attempt according to a column multi value return the message

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, login-attempts

`vendor` is a table which basic column have

```
id
account
password
status
```

- login need to check three columns `account`,`password`,`status`
- `vendor.status` have 4 types `'A','B','C','D'`,and want to login successfully the `vendor.status` should be `'A' or 'B'`, if the `vendor.status` not `'A' or 'B'` should return message according to the status, `vendor.status = 'C'`  return message `'failed login C !'`,`vendor.status = 'D'`  return message `'failed login D !'`

The question is:
How to return a message according to the `vendor.status` type when login failed?

How to write my laravel attempt?

---

for @Mehravish Temkar
As I know ,attempt return boolean value , but how I know the failed status is?
And `status` part is possible can be a multi value?

```
$attempt = auth()->guard('vendor')->attempt([
   'account'  => $request->account,
   'password' => $request->password,
   'status'   => 'A','B','C','D'
]);
```

Comment: can you share you code please

Comment: @MehravishTemkar I have update my code

Comment: try passing only account and password in attempt, and if true then you might wanna check further if the status is A,B,C or D, I am assuming that you don't know vendor status while login

Comment: is it working for you?

Comment: yes ! it works!

Comment: That's great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $attempt = auth()->guard('vendor')->attempt([ 
      'account' => $request->account, 
      'password' => $request->password 
 ]);
```

Don't pass status while you attempt to login. After successful login (when true) you could further check the status and accordingly logout the vendor again or do whatever action you want to do..